# Pingfederate Sample application - IDP authentication is completed and redirected to Service Provider but shows as No user logged in

Tags: single-sign-on, pingfederate

I am setting up sample SSO application using pingfederate.
After Clicking Single Sign-On to begin IdP-initiated SSO, it redirects to IDP login page.
After entering credentials, it authenticates the user and redirects back to service provider.
Authentication is successful but it shows No user is logged in.

I am new to pingfederate. can anyone help.

IDP URI: https://localhost:9031/IdpSample
SP URI: https://localhost:9031/SpSample